# how to pass props to html attributes

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem with html attributes and map. How to pass variables to html attrbutes? I have this code:

```
import React from "react";

export const AnimationParams = ({ children, animationparams }) => {
  animationparams;
  const number = animationparams.Parameters;
  const table = [...Array(number)];

  return table.map((_, index) => {
    const row = `Parameters_${index}_name`;
    const anchor = `Parameters_${index}_value`;

    return (
      <React.Fragment key={row}>
        <div
          className="animation"
          {...{ [animationparams[row]]: animationparams[anchor] }}
        >
          {children}
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  });
};
```

and on html I get:

```
<div>
<div class="animation" data-scroll="">
<h1 class="font-heading max-w-5xl mx-auto my-5 text-6xl ">To jest heading z acf/hero</h1>
</div>
<div class="animation" data-scroll-direction="horizontal">
<h1 class="font-heading max-w-5xl mx-auto my-5 text-6xl ">To jest heading z acf/hero</h1>
</div>
<div class="animation" data-scroll-speed="11">
<h1 class="font-heading max-w-5xl mx-auto my-5 text-6xl ">To jest heading z acf/hero</h1>
</div>
</div>
```

but i want:

```
<div>
<div class="animation" data-scroll data-scroll-direction="horizontal" data-scroll-speed="11"\>
<h1 class="font-heading max-w-5xl mx-auto my-5 text-6xl "\>To jest heading z acf/hero\</h1\>
<div>
</div>
```

this is   console.log(animationparams)

```
{
    "heading": "To jest heading z acf/hero",
    "_heading": "field_638a71fabc28a",
    "Parameters_0_name": "data-scroll",
    "_Parameters_0_name": "field_638b5c2392a98",
    "Parameters_0_value": "",
    "_Parameters_0_value": "field_638b5c2b92a99",
    "Parameters_1_name": "data-scroll-direction",
    "_Parameters_1_name": "field_638b5c2392a98",
    "Parameters_1_value": "horizontal",
    "_Parameters_1_value": "field_638b5c2b92a99",
    "Parameters_2_name": "data-scroll-speed",
    "_Parameters_2_name": "field_638b5c2392a98",
    "Parameters_2_value": "11",
    "_Parameters_2_value": "field_638b5c2b92a99",
    "Parameters": 3,
    "_Parameters": "field_638a7b858076a"
}
```

Comment: animationparams is a little odd for a data structure. Could you add it to the question?

Comment: I'ts only name, this could be htmlParams

Comment: Can you please add it?

Comment: Sorry but I dont understand... what I must to add?

Comment: before `return.table` please add a line `console.log(actionparams)` and add the printout from developer tools to the question

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the data structure you're using is extremely weird. Is is something you created yourself or does it come from some other component/api/backend/etc?

The issue you're having is that you are iterating over `Parameters` creating `div` tags when you want to do something like this (I didn't test it!)

```js
import React from "react";

export const AnimationParams = ({ children, animationparams }) => {
  const attributes = {};
  [...Array(animationparams.Parameters)].map((_, index) => {
    attributes[animationparams[`Parameters_${index}_name`]] = animationparams[`Parameters_${index}_value`]
  });

  return (
    <div
      className="animation"
      {...attributes}
    >
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Yes data it's from advanced custom fields from wordpress

Comment: Now I have:Server Error
TypeError: animationparams.Parameters.map is not a function

Comment: Updated to solve the bug but it's even more ugly now 

Comment: now i have "ReferenceError: index is not defined" so i changed index to i and now row is undefined.

Comment: what key i must to use?

Comment: Right should be `map(index =>`, updated. Sorry, Sunday morning and I'm not in my top form :P

Comment: No problem, thanks for help me :) ,sorry but now i have ReferenceError: row is not defined.

Comment: yes, your right :) i add to key={animationparams.Parameters} and it's ok but it's still doesn't work :( i dont have any parameters on div and when i console.log(attributes) in return it's show me undefined :/

Comment: ```import React from "react";

export const AnimationParams = ({ children, animationparams }) => {
  const attributes = {};
  animationparams;
  const number = animationparams.Parameters;
  const table = [...Array(number)];
  table.map((_, index) => {
    attributes[animationparams[`Parameters_${index}_name`]] =
      animationparams[`Parameters_${index}_value`];
  });

  return (
    <div className="animation" {...attributes}>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};
```